# Xor give error 'value too large'

Tags: vb.net, hex

Hi I try to convert the hex string to integer and then Xor with the second hex string but it give me the error. Below is my code. Please help. Thanks

```
Dim hex1 As String = "F5F2F1F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F1F1F7F5F4"
Dim hex2 As String = "F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8"
Dim dec1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(hex1, 16)
Dim dec2 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(hex2, 16)
Dim result As Integer = dec1 Xor dec2
Dim hexResult As String = result.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, "0")
Console.WriteLine(hexResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code falls apart *before*  reaching the `Xor` line. What you see as an [OverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx). You're trying to convert a value that is either *too large* or *too small* for an `Int32` (Ref. *dec1* and *dec1*).

**Int32** (Integer)

*[Minimum value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):*

> The value of this constant is -2,147,483,648; that is, hexadecimal 0x80000000.

*[Maximum value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):*

> The value of this constant is 2,147,483,647; that is, hexadecimal 0x7FFFFFFF.